# Set external gitlab web port

Tags: gitlab

I have installed the latest version of gitlab. I forgot to set the port in the EXTERNAL_URL variable during installation, so that I now need to change the port number. I have changed the external_url variable in gitlab.rb as mentioned in this question > https://serverfault.com/questions/585528/set-gitlab-external-web-port-number.
Gitlab is now accessible on this new port. However the previous port remains accessible (locally only, it seems) and is not freed (netstat shows that the process launching it is unicorn).

I rebooted the server, to no avail. I also tried changing the unicorn['port'] variable, but it doesn't work either.